# How to move working directory with Docker containers to another machine

Tags: docker

I am working on a Django project. I have a directory in my old laptop (Linux) having Docker containers. That directory contains my code. Now I want to move that working directory along with Docker containers to new laptop. I also want to keep environment intact.

I am new to Docker.

Comment: You should be able to check out a clean copy of your source repository on the new system, and re-run something like `docker-compose up --build` to rebuild all of the images and recreate all of the containers.  Does that work?

Comment: @DavidMaze But that will reset my databases and everything will start from fresh. I don't want that.

Comment: If your code and databases are all in containers (i.e. no on-host volumes) you can use `docker export` to create tarballs for each one, and `docker import` on the new computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched and found that the docker container can have linked database volumes to it.
So I followed the following steps:

1. Copy directory to another machine
2. Create a backup of database volume(in my case it was Postgresql)
3. Build images from the directory in the new machine.
4. Restore the database from the backup-database file.